# d3.js initialization error IE11

Tags: javascript, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

I've got a problem with displaying a nvd3 chart in IE11. It seems that the initialization process of d3.js is throwing an error as even if i comment out my code the error still occurs.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'key' of undefined or null reference
>   d3.v3.js (8185,5)

This seems odd to me, as the d3 homepage explicitly states that IE9+ is supported. Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Comment: Do you have some code that reproduces your error?  Both `d3` and `nvd3` support IE11...

Comment: As I said, i don't need to run any code. Simply loading https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js produces this error

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that a little hack I did to solve [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1046039/classlist-not-working-on-svg-elements) was causing the problem. Basically I used the object prototype to add the classList functionalities to svg elements. Since I don't need the classList property with my chart, this should not be an issue.